# Пунктуация в стихотворении И. Бродского «И вечный бой...»

Tags: запятые, как, однородные-члены, авторская-пунктуация, поэзия

Вот [отрывок](https://www.culture.ru/poems/31032/i-vechnyi-boi) из стихотворения Иосифа Бродского.

> Простите нас.
>   Мы до конца кипели,(1)
>   и мир воспринимали,(2)
>   как бруствер.
>   Сердца рвались,
>   метались и храпели,(3)
>   как лошади,
>   попав под артобстрел.

Если бы я оформляла знаки, то в указанных местах не поставила бы запятые.
Понимаю, что авторская пунктуация — дело особенное.
Тем не менее подскажите, нужны ли указанные запятые? Как их можно объяснить?

Comment: А третья запятая Вас чем смущает?

Comment: Согласна. Третья запятая на месте.

Comment: Встречаются и варианты без запятой №1, "И вечный бой": https://www.booksite.ru/localtxt/bro/dsk/ii/brodskii_i_a/sochineniya/2.htm#5. Насколько я понимаю, это что-то из раннего и малоизвестного. Сказать с уверенностью, как в нём расставлял запятые сам автор - достаточно сложно.

Answer (score 2):

Римма, здесь пунктуация передаёт сбивчивость разговорной речи. Это речевая характеристика, не слова автора, а речь героя от имени погибших простых солдат.

Повторяющиеся в стихотворении многоточия (... Скажите... там...
чтоб больше не будили) создают эффект устной речи, когда говорящий делает паузы, запинается то ли от усталости, то ли от нерешительности. А чуть выше - приведённые Вами строки, там этот же ритм - отдельные рубленые фразы, разделённые точкой, запятой, многоточием (по типу присоединения).

В общем, это художественная особенность. Единство формы и содержания. В этом стихотворении тема войны присутствует на всех уровнях текста. Интересен ритм стихотворения. Строки разбиты так, что в них то по два, то по три ударения. И только в двух строках – пять ударений. Можно предположить, что такой ритм стихотворения – это дробление, разрыв пятистопного размера на две и три стопы. Разрыв ритма, разрыв бомб, разрыв тел лошадей, людей… Война врывается даже в ритм стихотворения, который склеивается только дважды – когда хаос побеждается «синей тишиной» (стих 7) и когда на фоне разрывов целостность жизни всё-таки восстанавливается пусть не в действительности, но в желаниях солдат: «А мы хотели просто уцелеть» (стих 14).

Последняя, четвёртая строфа разделена на два четверостишия. Первое четверостишие (стихи 23–26) относится к будущему. Это обращение солдат с просьбой передать какой-то высшей инстанции, чтобы их больше не будили. Можно предположить, что это «там» (24), которое имеет власть над умершими, может быть, сам Бог, который разбудит живых и мёртвых на последний суд. А может, и те, по чьему приказу на военных парадах в честь победы вновь и вновь должны называться имена павших, должна тревожиться их память. А им теперь уже ничего не нужно, только тишина и покой.

В пользу версии разговорной прерывистой речи говорит и разговорная лексика.
 Оборот «что из того, что…» несёт на себе черты просторечия, нарочитой грубоватости, и даже неграмотности с точки зрения нормативного русского языка. Особенно эта разговорность бросается в глаза по контрасту с высокими поэтизмами первой строфы и искусным переплетением метафор и сравнений с военными терминами в третьей и четвертой строфах. В последней строфе присутствует некий вызов, солдаты отказываются от посмертного внимания к их судьбам и одновременно грубовато-беспомощно извиняются, оправдывают свою гибель, которая ждала их раньше победы.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Конечно же Вы во многом правы. Я помню, как мой дед (1912) во время праздничных салютов в честь дня Победы грустно качал головой и говорил, что это напоминает ему взрывы. Он считал, что скорбеть надо в тишине.

Answer (score 1):

Единственная причина, по которой, по моему мнению, в стихотворении могут быть нужны запятая 1 и запятая 2, это ситуация, когда фраза "и мир воспринимали" является вставной по отношению к выражению "мы до конца кипели, как бруствер". То есть Бродский подчёркивает, что хочет сказать сразу две мысли: "Мы до конца кипели, как бруствер" и "мы воспринимали мир как бруствер". Если бы он, скажем, не поставил бы запятую 2, то получилось бы две мысли: "мы до конца кипели" и "мы мир воспринимали как бруствер". Наличие же запятых позволяет связать "кипели" со сравнением с бруствером. А как же он кипит? Ну, Бродскому виднее. Может, под градом пуль он и в самом деле может видеться поэту чем-то кипящим.

Конечно, пунктуация при этом будет всё равно очень и очень авторская. Да и само сравнение лично для меня не выглядит убедительным. Я вообще придерживаюсь мнения, что это ошибочные или интонационные запятые. Но захотелось порассуждать на тему того, что способны дать стихотворению эти два лишних знака препинания. На мой взгляд, только лишь обозначить "изымаемость" фразы, чтобы связать две другие, те, что по бокам.

А вот третья запятая действительно на месте. Это сравнение. Оно не является устойчивым выражением, не входит в сказуемое, а потому запятая там обязательна.

Comment: Не все, к сожалению, поняла, но — спасибо!