# Запятые в стихотворении И. Бродского

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, поэзия

*Ты, в коричневом пальто,

я, исчадье распродаж.*

Почему здесь присутствуют эти запятые?

Answer (score 1):

Это отрывок их стихотворения Иосифа Бродского «В горах».

Я думаю, что запятые тут показывают паузы, которые нужно делать при чтении стихотворения:

Ты [пауза] в коричневом пальто,
я [пауза] исчадье распродаж.
Ты [пауза] никто, и я [пауза] никто.
Вместе мы [пауза] почти пейзаж.

---

Вот тут есть вопрос по пунктуации Бродского: [Пунктуация в стихотворении И. Бродского «И вечный бой…»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460018/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%98-%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%98-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9)

А вот тут про [Интонационные запятые](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29984/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5).

Answer (score 1):

В этих предложениях (два простые в составе БСП) нет сказуемого, оно было бы при тире, когда что-то является чем-то.

Здесь другая интонация. Читается так, как просто номинативные (назывные) предложения: *ты, я*. В оригинальном варианте они также ими являются, наличие обособления на это не влияет. После этих местоимений идёт не сказуемое, а **определительное добавление**, подобно следующему:
*Видно тебя, в коричневом пальто, видно меня, исчадье распродаж.*
Во второй части оно выражает подлежащее, являясь приложением и отвечая на вопрос "кто именно?", а в первой — нет, являясь обособленным дополнением и отвечая на вопрос "в чём?".

Это нестандартный (редкий) ход, потому что обособленные приложения обычно используются там, где уже есть сказуемое, а где его нет — сами им становятся (без обособления).

А дальше в стихе уже идёт выражение через тире (со сказуемым):
*Ты — никто, и я — никто.

Вместе мы — почти пейзаж.*

Comment: «Исчадье распродаж» — можно посчитать приложением, а вот «в коричневом пальто» — сомнительно. Приложение находится в том же роде, числе и падеже. А тут «ты» — именительный падеж, а «в коричневом пальто» — предложный падеж.

Comment: *Приложение — это определение, выраженное **согласованным именем существительным без предлога или несогласованным существительным в форме именительного падежа**. Приложение даёт дополнительное название, характеризующее предмет [[izamorfix.ru](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/prilozhenie.html)].* Я вас не понимаю. Какое отношение имеет к делу, подлежащее это или нет? Тут есть предлог «в» и существительное не согласовано и не выражено именительным падежом — значит это не приложение.

Comment: Ок, исправил...

Comment: oleedd, как я думаю, вы ближе всего к истине, но нечетко определили грамматику. Эти конструкции являются номинативными, а не читаются как номинативные. А обособленные обороты не уточняющие, а определительные.

Comment: Ну да, читаются, потому что являются. Надо же было как-то объяснить, как оно читается. Сказал бы, что определительное добавление.

Answer (score 1):

**Интонация** здесь – не главное, для  постановки знаков препинания важно правильно определить **грамматику**.

Это **номинативные** (назывные) распространенные предложения. Основное значение номинативных предложений — бытийное, т.е. существование предмета или явления. При этом говорится  не только о существовании, но и о наличии предмета **в поле зрения**  воспринимающего лица.

Номинативные предложения допускают **распространение** только определением, согласованным или несогласованным. И вот у Бродского не совсем привычный вариант, а именно о**бособленные определения и приложения.** Но от этого суть номинативных предложений не меняется – это все те же предметы в зоне внимания  поэта.

В стихотворении около 20 строф, многие из которых имеют **одинаковую структуру**: две строки включают номинативные предложения, а две другие – это предложения двусоставные. И мы видим, какие **разнообразные определения** использует Бродский.

***Ты**, в коричневом пальто,*

***я**, исчадье распродаж.*

*Ты – никто, и я – никто.*

*Вместе мы – почти пейзаж.*

Здесь обособленное несогласованное определение (***в коричневом пальто***) и обособленное приложение (***исчадье распродаж***),  которые отнесены к личным местоимениям.

Другие варианты:

*Белых склонов **тишь да гладь**.*

***Стук** в долине молотка.*

*На ночь снятое **пальто**.*

***Трепыханье** фитиля.*

А это уже **обособленное согласованное** определение,  включающее однородный ряд дополнений:

*Горный **пик**, доступный снам,*

*фотопленке, свалке туч.*

**Интонация и постановка запятых** полностью соответствует грамматике  номинативных и обособленных конструкций.

Анализ стихотворения Бродского «В горах»

http://parnasse.ru/klassika/brodskii-iosif-aleksandrovich-1940-1996/iosif-brodskii-v-gorah.html

«Это стихотворение сложно для восприятия. Оно написано в типичной для поэта  манере: в нём часто встречаются **инверсии, метафоры, разорванные фразы**. Оно само по себе – поток затейливых образов…  Но за всем этим скрывается серьёзное философское размышление о скоротечности жизни и о её назначении».

Comment: На интонации user199591 не настаивал и даже не поминал её (вопрос-то девственно чист).

Comment: Зато отвечающие настаивали - в каждом ответе интонация.  А решение здесь грамматическое.

Comment: Хорошо, но странно, без разгона... Может, user не читал ещё ничего, его этот ответ привлёк, к примеру, объёмом и массой чёрных букв?

Comment: Надеюсь, что привлек, но не уверена, user нам ничего пишет... Черными буквами обозначены предметные существительные в номинативных  предложениях, а то их не сразу найдешь. Исключительно для удобства пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы на месте запятых было по тире, то тире обозначало бы паузу после слов под логическим ударением и все это звучало бы как противопоставление. Как вот такое предложение: «Я — победитель, ты — проигравший». Но здесь(даже отдаленно не представляю смысл этих строк), видимо, перечисляются слова «я» и «ты», а после них следует по вставной конструкции, которые произносятся интонацией отступления(как и любая вставная конструкция). Будет более понятно, если привести пример на предложении, которое не является стихотворным полубредом. Вот предложение, где перечисляются люди и делается отступление с короткой информацией о них: «Джек, странный тип, Сьюзи, наркоманка, Филип, в психлечебнице».